# Redirect url based on ID using lua

Tags: api, http, nginx, lua, nginx-config

I'm extremely new to Lua as well as nginx.we're trying to set up authentication. 
 I'm trying to write a script that could be injected in my NGINX which would actually listen to a an endpoint.

My api would give give me a token. I would receive this token and check if it exists in my YAML file or probably JSON file .

based on the privilege mentioned in the file, I would like to redirect it the respective url with necessary permissions.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: nginx doesn't have any non-blocking disk I/O, so you should reconsider the file-based solution, or set up a simple "upstream" service to check the token **if** you need to process lots of requests per second.

Comment: Will the upstream service allow me to do condition based routing? Sorry for sounding like a noob but I'm completely new here..

Comment: You can put all the logic in nginx, of course. The problem is that, when nginx opens a file for reading, the entire worker process stops until it's done reading said file from disk, which you usually wouldn't want.

Comment: Of course you can also just load the json or yaml file *once* when you start the server (`init_by_lua_block`) and then just leave it in memory to be used during validation (`rewrite_by_lua_block`).

Comment: how do I read and parse a json file using lua? Does that require any extra package installations? We'll be using openResty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, nginx on its own has no Lua integration whatsoever; so if you just have an nginx server, you can't script it in Lua at all.

What you probably mean is openresty, aka. the lua-nginx-module, which lets you run Lua code in nginx to handle requests programatically.

---

Assuming that you have a working nginx + lua-nginx-module installed and running, what you're looking for is the [`rewrite_by_lua`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#rewrite_by_lua) directive, which lets you redirect the client to a different address based on their request.
(Realistically, you'd likely want to use `rewrite_by_lua_block` or `rewrite_by_lua_file` instead)

Within the Lua block, you can make API calls, execute some logic, etc. and then redirect to some URI internally with [`ngx.exec`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#ngxexec) or send an actual redirect to the client with [`ngx.redirect`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#ngxredirect).

If you want to read in a JSON or YAML file, you should do so in the [`init_by_lua`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#rewrite_by_lua) so the file gets loaded only *once* and then stays in memory. The `lua-cjson` module comes with nginx, so you can just use that to parse your json data into a Lua table.